# What is the best and most secure way to encrypt Ajax data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, security

I'm developing a website where people will be able to register and access different data via Ajax (powered by jQuery). This is all simple and i shall have no problems doing. the issue is that the data showed by Ajax needs to be secure and not available to be parsed through remote scripts. I can encrypted the data through a AES (in PHP) and decrypt successfully in javascript, but the javascript code will always be visible to everyone (after login). I can use an obfuscator and javascript encryption, but both ways, even mixed, are not secure enough and decryptable. I would prefer avoiding SSL connections, since I am trying to prevent registered users from accessing the information and the SSL connection would only prevent unregistered users from accessing the data.

Registered users will be able to earn money therefore very interested in cheating the code, this is why it has to be bulletproof.

Unfortunately the system needs definitely Ajax (the whole working principle needs to be based on Ajax). The ideal solution would be a way to save the encryption key on a place that can be saved by php and accessed by javascript, but not by users, remote script parsers etc.

Does anyone know a way to create a secure Ajax connection for this purpose?

I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What kind of data are you going to send to the server and what actions you think the users could currently do in order to *cheat* your system whatever this means.

Comment: If javascript can see it, clever users can see it. There is no way around that.

Comment: Do you mean enrypting the data so that someone observing the network traffic cannot see the data, or so that the user cannot see what their own browser is sending, or both?

Comment: We need to know what exactly you need to secure.

Comment: I want the users to be able to see the data only when Ajax displays them. There is going to be a questionaire and i need to prevent them from finding the encryption key in the javascript code and copying+decoding the questions and answers directly from php. I don't care about the traffic observers as the data is AES encrypted. 
@Jcubed - unfortunately I read this already i'm searching for the best mixed solution to prevent this.

Comment: @Czakalli: What you try to achieve is most certainly conceptually broken.

Comment: @Hakre would you mind explaining? - does it mean that is impossible as Jcubed said? What would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: @Czakalli: There is absolutely no way to prevent this. Your only option is it make it harder, which is just a waste of time. You would be much better off spending your time thinking of a solution that does not involve giving javascript something you don't want users to see.

Comment: It sounds like you need to send one question at a time.

Comment: @Czakalli: Not at all. The HTTP client is sending a request to the HTTP server which will reply to that request. This communication is transferred over networks unencrypted and can be seen by everybody. Next to that the information of the request is explicitly available in both endpoints: client and server.

Comment: If a user can operate your system, then so can anything that behaves like a user. You have to implement all your policy enforcement on the server.

Answer (score 8):

You want something that browsers do not do.

You've asked for: `"The ideal solution would be a way to save the encryption key on a place that can be saved by php and accessed by javascript, but not by users, remote script parsers etc."`

The design of the web browser and javascript engine in the browser is such that any Javascript that the web browser can execute can be seen by a human who wants to look at it, steal it, borrow it, whatever.  Period.  There is NO such place that can be accessed by Javascript, but not by users or remote script parsers.  You will have to rethink how your app works if this is a problem.  Most likely, you need to keep the secret stuff on the server and do more work on the server and less work on the client in order to protect what you want to protect.  If you think about it, a browser is just a remote script parser so if you prevent remote script parsing, you prevent a browser.  If you allow a browser, you allow a remote script parser.

You can obfuscate your Javascript to your heart's content if you want.  That will make it a little more work for a human to understand and do something useful with it, but it will only be an additional obstacle that any determined and competent person can defeat if they really want to.  If this secrecy is really important to you, then you need to rethink the design of the app so that secret information is not required in the browser and the browser just works as a display and interaction engine.

Just so I'm clear here.  Any code that can be executed by a browser must, by definition, be something that any user or any tool can download and inspect.  You can use SSL to protect data from snoopers in transport, but it ultimately has to be readable as Javascript for the browser to be able to execute it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this is exactly what i was afraid of. the issue is that the server load is a real concern here. I'm starting with 50 000 users and the goal will be 1 mil playing users at the same time. This is why i need javascript to handle part of the load. Even if i put everything in php, a bot will always be able to get the questions, analyze them and respond faster, then any human can.

Comment: Sometimes bots can be challenged by putting questions in images instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want. It's like a cheat-proof game design. You CAN make it HARDER, even MORE hard, but NOT 100% secure. You've got to solve the problem froma different approach, like, whatever that is, examine the actions at server-side (e.g. in a stateful manner) and try to detect any non-human behavior. But it's only a matter of someone creating a realistic bot that mimicks the behavior of humans. Encryption is used for preventing 3rd parties -- other than the server and the client -- from eavesdropping/capturing data, NOT for the client. I'm not saying give up on the whole thing, but try a different approach to secure the system. I want to help more, but don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Generally for making it harder the developer spends N hours and the hackers spend an extra n hours fighting it. The hacker always have more manhours then the developer so after n > cut-off its a losing battle.

Comment: Exactly, forgot to mention that. They spent hard time making PlayStation 3 / iPhone / Windows Phone (and many more) secure from being hacked/jailbroken by the users, then, we've seen the results :)

Comment: Thanks can poyrazoğlu, Ryanos, I understand there is no 100% secure way to prevent this. How would you advise to be the best way to prevent users from finding the decryption key in the js code? Do you know of a secure and good php js obfuscator that can automatically obfuscate the js code with a changeable key before sending it to the user? This way if i change the encryption keys every day? This way the hacker will loose interest fast enough as will have to analyze the code everyday from scratch.

Comment: @Czakalli you can't. Only give authorised users the minimal data they should need. Any data JavaScript needs authorised users can see. Just bind the encyrption key to every single block of data. So have a unique key for each piece of data.

Comment: @CzakalliAs: a rule of the thumb, if a scripting engine/parser/virtual machine etc. **at the client side** CAN access it (as it needs to access to run it anyway), then any malicious user or program under a malicious user's control too. you simple can not (and shouldn't) trust on the client side. nice to leave it as a "not easily crackable" client code and do the real job completely on server side, with ALL the validations for the input that would come from the client side too. believe me, it's easy to crack code at client side. you wouldn't want that for your own good :)

Answer (score -1):

authentication is the only ways to do it.

Just get your users to authenticate (login) and send them the random seed and salt you've used to encrypt their data.

Without the seed/salt, even though a malicious user can decrypt your data it will still be garbage.

If you want javascript to use a piece of data then clients use that data.

If you don't want data to be re-used set up a server-side system where each chunk of data is only valid once.

Proper authentication should solve all these problems.

> I want the users to be able to see the data only when Ajax displays them

Then load the data when ajax get's it and not before. Or only partially load data and off-load any sensitive work to the server.

Comment: He is trying to prevent a valid user from gaming his system.  So the problem still exists.

Comment: https only protects the data from snoopers as it's being transported.  It does not protect the data once it gets onto the system and comes out the end of the secure https tunnel into the browser.  It works well for preventing many man-in-the-middle attacks or eavesdropping, but that isn't the issue here.

Comment: @Raynos the authenticated user is the malicious user.

Comment: @AaronFischer I still don't see what the malicious user can do with the data. As long as they only have the minimal amount of data they need I can't see what they can game.

Comment: @Raynos I think Czakalli wanted to send all the questions( and answers) down to the client at once.  Otherwise I am not sure what the point of this question was.

Answer (score -1):

i think the best practice is to make your code (production code) too mush complex to read and edit 
you should rename all your variable with letters [a-z] you should not declare ny function always use `function(){}` inside of another to make it more logical complex this way 
the client can still see the code  but has nothing to do with it 
EDIT: I realize now it's a terrible advice

Comment: Security through obscurity isn`t a thing. It`s like burying your money under a tree. The only security is that no one knows its there, but others can still dig it up.